# How to check if a Python module with a custom __getattr__ has a given attribute?

Tags: python, python-module, getattr

I implemented a custom `__getattr__` on [a module](https://github.com/bfontaine/Anycode/blob/d7442b42fabbc6922f06bda284e0844d79f4b0c3/anycode/__init__.py#L12) that retrieves a value and caches it with `setattr`. Here is the simplified version:

```py
# mymodule.py
import sys

__this = sys.modules[__name__]


def __getattr__(name: str):
    print(f"Generating {name}")
    value = "some value"
    setattr(__this, name, value)
    return value
```

This works fine:

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> mymodule.foo
Generating foo
'some value'
>>> mymodule.bar
Generating bar
'some value'
>>> mymodule.bar
'some value'
```

Note how `__getattr__` is called only on attributes that don’t already exist on the module. How can I identify these attributes? Python obviously knows about them, but I can’t get that information.

`hasattr` doesn’t work, because under the hood it calls `getattr` which calls my function:

```
>>> hasattr(mymodule, "foo")
True
>>> hasattr(mymodule, "something")
Generating something
True
```

`"foo" in dir(mymodule)` works, but it requires to enumerate *all* attributes with `dir()` to test for a single one. One can delete attributes with `del mymodule.foo`, so keeping track of them in `__getattr__` using a global `set` doesn’t work (and having a custom `__delattr__` [is not supported yet](https://peps.python.org/pep-0726/)).

How can I test if "something" is an attribute of `mymodule` without calling `mymodule.__getattr__`?

Comment: If you care about the distinction, implementing `__getattr__` in the first place may not be the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules are objects in Python, and just like most objects, they have a `__dict__`.

```
>>> mymodule.__dict__
{...}
>>> "foo" in mymodule.__dict__
True
>>> "something" in mymodule.__dict__
False
```

Keep in mind that `__dict__` also contains certain things that you don't explicitly define, like `__name__` and `__doc__` (which exist on all modules). Though attempting to access these would *not* invoke your `__getattr__` anyway, so it's consistent with the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you; that’s perfect! I don’t know why I didn’t think about it.